# How to attach custom/existing screenshot in allure report?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, allure

Generally, I am using below code to take a screenshot and attach in allure report :

```
@Attachment(value = "Page Screenshot", type = "image/png")
public static byte[] saveScreenshotPNG(WebDriver driver) {
    return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

But now my need is I have already some screenshot on `my desktop` and want to attach it with an allure report. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the existing image and convert it to `byte[]`. `getScreenshotAs()` decodes the screenshot string so you might need to do it as well

**Java**

```
@Attachment(value = "Page Screenshot", type = "image/png")
public static byte[] saveScreenshotPNG(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);

    byte[] image = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", bos);
        image = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    // if decoding is not necessary just return image
    return image != null ? Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(image) : null;
}
```

**Python**

```
with open(path, 'rb') as image:
    file = image.read()
    byte_array = bytearray(file)
    allure.attach(byte_array, name="Screenshot", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. @Guy, Do you mind giving the same code for python also, please? I need same in python and allure as well. Currently, I am using         `allure.attach(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Screenshot", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)`

Comment: @HelpingHands Updated. The Python solution is even tested.